# Seasonality and trend window in the Forecast functions of R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, seasonality, trend

I have time-series power consumption data for one month. The data is sampled at minutes frequency. Thus, for each day I have 1440 observations and for the month (30 days) I have 4320 observations. On the same data, I use `stl()` function to observe seasonality, trend, etc. I have following doubts:

1. What should be the frequency value while creating the `ts` (timeSeries) object? Is it 1440 (no. of observations per day) or it is 30 (no. of days for which observations are recorded)
2. In the `stl` function, I need to provide values for `s.window`, `t.window`. Should I use the value of frequency for `s.window`? I am clueless about trend window.

I am following [this](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/1) page to understand these concepts.

**UPDATE**

1. My Ist doubt got cleared while reading this [page](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/), where Dr. Rob mentions that frequency is the number of observations per season. Thus, the answer to my first doubt is 1440 as season is represented by each day in my data.

Comment: About `stl`, did you already read the associated paper?

Comment: I read the associated book chapter, but  still unable to understand the relation between  `s.window` and `frequency`. I find the seasonality, more intuitive while setting `s.window` to 30 as compared to 1440

Comment: Although asked in terms of an R function, these questions seem clearly statistical to me. IMO, this should be considered on topic here.

Comment: @gung, Yes, this is a statistical question. If this is not the correct place to ask this question, then can you please refer me to the correct place.